# MVC database table required for each model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

i am new to MVC, i am just trying to build a simple website.
And i am using EF code first. My problem is that MVC always looking for a database table for a model that i do not want permanent storage, (i will just initialize an object of it when i use it)
Here is my code:

```
public class Family
{
    public int FamilyId { get; set; }
    public String FamilyName { get; set; }
    public String FamilyJoinString { get; set; }
    public String MemberIds { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FamilyMember> Members { get; set; }


    public List<FamilyMember> GetFamilyMembers()
    {
        var db = new HomeTrackerDb();
        var CommonHelper = new CommonHelper();
        var members = new List<FamilyMember>();
        var memberids = MemberIds;
        var ids = CommonHelper.SplitToList(memberids, ",");
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            var user = db.UserInfoes.Find(int.Parse(id));
            var member = new FamilyMember();
            member.FamilyMemberId = user.UserInfoId;
            member.FamilyMemberName = user.UserName;
            member.FamilyMemberLoad = 0;
            members.Add(member);
        }
        db.Dispose();
        return members;
    }

}

    //FamilyMember Class
    public class FamilyMember
    {
        public int FamilyMemberId { get; set; }
        public String FamilyMemberName { get; set; }
        public int FamilyMemberLoad { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am generating the list of FamilyMember only in a controller, and do not have DB update, insert and find operations. 
Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Family family = db.Families.Find(id);
        family.Members = family.GetFamilyMembers();                       
        return View(family);
    }
```

But MVC is always saying Cannot Find database table FamilyMembers.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Family is a table on your database, and the class Family is an entity that maps to your Family table.

Since you have `List<FamilyMember> Members` as a property of your Family class, EF is trying to map that property to a related table.

In order to signal to EF to not map that property, add the `[NotMapped]` attribute:

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual List<FamilyMember> Members { get; set; }
```

This is assuming you're not using Fluent API. If you're using Fluent, then you would specify it like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Family>().Ignore(t => t.Members);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You specify `public virtual List<FamilyMember> Members { get; set; }` that is automatically converted into table mapping, e.g. [similar mapping](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/07/23/my-favorite-features-entity-framework-code-first-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx).

If you don't want to map property in your example you can change it visibility to `internal`, but I will suggest don't use such solution at all, better way as for me is:

```
public class Family
{
    [Key]
    public int FamilyId { get; set; }
    public String FamilyName { get; set; }
    public String FamilyJoinString { get; set; }

    public IList<UserInfoes> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Family
{
    [Key]
    public int UserInfoId { get; set; }
    public Family Family { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just confused about the difference between my Member obj and other class. Is it mapped just because i have A LIST of that in another class? Because for a normal class, MVC wont map it if i dont specify it in DbContext.